# Can't add Google account for syncing contacts on iOS

Tags: ios, contacts, google

I want to sync my Google contacts on my iPhone.

When I try to add my Google account on `Settings > Contacts > Accounts > Add Account > Google`, it show me the login page, but when I finish logging in it briefly (about 1 sec.) show me the page with the "Gmail" title where I can select the services to synchronize (Mail, Contacts, Calendars and Notes) and go back to the "Add Account" page without adding the account.

I have tried on several iPhone models, on Wi-Fi and on a mobile network, the problem is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not have a Gmail account on my Google account (account created with an external email address) and that the addition crashes because iOS tries to configure the Mail application with the account.

To solve the problem, add the account through: `Settings > Contacts > Accounts > Add Account > Other > Add CardDAV Account` and add the information as follows:

- Server: google.com
- Username: the mail address of your Google account
- Password: your Google account password<sup>1</sup>
- Description: what you want

<sup>1</sup> If your Google account has two-factor authentication configured, you must enter an [app password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en) instead of your account password.

You can do the same if you want to configure the calendar and the notes through `Settings > Contacts > Accounts > Add Account > Other > Add CallDAV Account`.